# Connecting to GO websocket server running on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a websocket server built with go running on AWS beanstalk. I'm running a load balancer with a SSL cert. I'm having issues connecting to it via the browser. If I try to connect to it through another go program running on my terminal everything works fine. I've updated my environment to accept `TCP` instead of `HTTP` connections on port `80`.

When I try to connect from the webapp though I get this error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://root.com/users/fcbd7f8d-2ef6-4fe2-b46c-22db9b107214/sockets/client' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

When I check the AWS logs I find this error.

```
the client is not using the websocket protocol: 
'websocket' token not found in 'Upgrade' header
```

**UPDATE**

if I run the webapp on my localhost and change the connection string from `wss://` to `ws://` it works. If I try the same url in the live webapp I get an ssl error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://root.com/captions' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 
'ws://root.com/users/fcbd7f8d-2ef6-4fe2-b46c-22db9b107214/sockets/client'. 
This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using https://godoc.org/net/http#example-ListenAndServeTLS

Comment: @RayfenWindspear the load balancer removes https

Comment: Explain in more detail what you mean by "I've updated my environment to accept TCP instead of HTTP connections on port 80.".   I am not sure that that means given that HTTP runs over TCP.

Comment: Are you using wss: when the page is served from https: and ws: when the page is served from http:?